# Vertex label in igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I'm new to igraph. I tried this simple code but it is not displaying the vertiex id inside the node.

```
from igraph import *
g = Graph()
g.add_vertices(3)
g.add_edges([(0,1), (1,2)])
plot(g, layout = g.layout("kk"))
```

Can anyone please tell me as to why the id's are not displayed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the IDs are not displayed as labels by default ;) If you want to show them, you have to set the `label` attribute of each node to its label or specify `vertex_label=...` as a keyword argument to `plot`:

```
g.vs["label"] = range(g.vcount())
```

or

```
plot(g, layout="kk", vertex_label=range(g.vcount())
```